# regular expression NAND operator

Tags: regex

I have having trouble extracting information from a log, (see below)

```
Account Name: - Account Domain: - Logon ID: 0x0 Account Name: 
usefulinfo Account Domain: whatever
```

i tried to use

```
(?=Account Name\: )(.*?)(?=Account Domain)
```

but that gets both match groups, including the first match group "-"

All I need is to extract the 'usefulinfo' from the second matching group. Not sure how to achieve this. Is there a NAND operator or better regex expression?

Thanks to you all

Comment: Whats your expected output exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
(?=Account Name\: )([^-]*?)(?=Account Domain)
```

[Demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/uN2gP6/1)

Comment: Welcome.. If this answer helped you.. you can accept it by clicking the tick mark above.. this will help others to know that this is correct answer and also gives you and me some reputation :P.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using

```
(?<=Account Name: )([^-]|.{2,})(?=Account Domain)
```

This will match any single character that is not a `-`, or anything with 2 or more characters, except for newlines.

Also, the first lookahead should be changed to a lookbehind, otherwise the regex engine will include that in the match, since it matches `([^-]|.{2,})` too.
And as far as I know, you don't need to escape `:`.

Comment: Thank you Siguza, but your regular expression matched everything in between, the whole "Account Domain: - Logon ID: 0x0 Account Name: 
usefulinfo " is matched. Karthik provided a better result